# Jupyter fails to open notebook with error: 'File "XX" has unsaved changes, close without saving?'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupyter notebooks on a cluster of machines which use a distributed file system.

After some time, I am unable to open a new notebooks because of an error:

```sh
Close without saving?
File "XXX.ipynb" has unsaved changes, close without saving?
```

Looking at the Jupyter logs, I can see that this error arrises because the `nbsignatures.db` database is locked.

```sh
[E 15:58:01.190 LabApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents/workspace/proteinsolver/notebooks/XXX.ipynb?type=notebook&content=1&1572638276143 (10.74.73.2)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:9416', method='GET', uri='/api/contents/workspace/proteinsolver/notebooks/04_sudoku_train-01-Copy8.ipynb?type=notebook&content=1&1572638276143', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='10.74.73.2')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
        path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 433, in get
        model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 392, in _notebook_model
        self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 508, in mark_trusted_cells
        trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 439, in check_signature
        return self.store.check_signature(signature, self.algorithm)
      File "/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 232, in check_signature
        """, (algorithm, digest)).fetchone()
    sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

What is the easiest way for me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any chance the notebook is being maintained in git and there was a merge conflict? See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61031136/4001214 it fixed mine when I had this problem.

When git can't resolve a conflict in a text file, it puts its idea of plausible diffs inside the file. This breaks the JSON structure of the .ipynb and makes it unreadable in jupyter. In the linked solution, the author shows

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  },
  {
   <CONTENTS OF MY CELL>
   ]
=======
>>>>>>> a23f8f8f9db0974b7de90c6e7ed8599fa04d53cc
```

and notes that deleting the offending lines from the file with a text editor solved the issue. In my case, I had a known good file in git, so I deleted the local copy and re-pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter uses a SQLite database to write notebook signatures, and [as reported previously](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/150), SQLite does not behave well on distributed filesystems.

First, we need to generate a Jupyter config file (it is not created by default):

```sh
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then we need to edit this config file (`jupyter_notebook_config.py`) to set the default SQLite storage engine to `:memory:`:

```py
c.NotebookNotary.db_file = ':memory:'
```

Opening new notebooks should no longer require a call to the database!