# Error when opening .ipynb in JupyterLab - "Close without saving?"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

When I try to **open** my `.ipynb`, I get the following error. Other notebooks in the same directory work just fine.

**UI Error:**

```
Close without saving?
File "cloner.ipynb" has unsaved changes, close without saving?Close without saving?
File "cloner.ipynb" has unsaved changes, close without saving?
```

**Browser console errors:**

```
serverconnection.js:192 GET http://localhost:8890/api/contents/cloner.ipynb?type=notebook&content=1&1586015957921 400 (Bad Request)
handleRequest @ serverconnection.js:192
makeRequest @ serverconnection.js:76
get @ index.js:477
get @ index.js:170
(anonymous) @ context.js:498
Promise.then (async)
_revert @ context.js:497
initialize @ context.js:190
(anonymous) @ manager.js:445
Promise.then (async)
_createOrOpenDocument @ manager.js:445
open @ manager.js:274
openOrReveal @ manager.js:298
_handleOpen @ listing.js:824
_evtDblClick @ listing.js:900
handleEvent @ listing.js:543


context.js:582 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream is locked
    at Context._handleError (context.js:582)
    at context.js:540
_handleError @ context.js:582
(anonymous) @ context.js:540
async function (async)
_handleError @ context.js:582
(anonymous) @ context.js:540
async function (async)
(anonymous) @ context.js:536
Promise.catch (async)
_revert @ context.js:533
initialize @ context.js:190
(anonymous) @ manager.js:445
Promise.then (async)
_createOrOpenDocument @ manager.js:445
open @ manager.js:274
openOrReveal @ manager.js:298
_handleOpen @ listing.js:824
_evtDblClick @ listing.js:900
handleEvent @ listing.js:543
```

**Pip-managed package versions:**

```
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.

Name: jupyterlab
Version: 2.0.1
Summary: The JupyterLab notebook server extension.
```

I tried deleting my `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder, and am tracking all this stuff in git.

> Looking at the Jupyter logs, I can see that this error arrises because the `nbsignatures.db` database is locked. https://www.onooks.com/jupyter-fails-to-open-notebook-with-error-file-xx-has-unsaved-changes-close-without-saving/

Comment: uh,oh. bad json -- CLI error:    `[W 15:58:59.601 NotebookApp] 400 GET /api/contents/cloner.ipynb?type=notebook&content=1&1586015939594 (127.0.0.1): Unreadable Notebook: /home/layne.sadler/Desktop/neurodb/cloner.ipynb NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: \'{\\n "cells": [\\n  {\\n   "cell_type": "m...')`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a git merge conflict added non-json lines to my file.

Looking inside `cloner.ipynb` source file w text editor:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  },
  {
   <CONTENTS OF MY CELL>
   ]
=======
>>>>>>> a23f8f8f9db0974b7de90c6e7ed8599fa04d53cc
```

Deleted those non-json lines and am back in business.

Comment: Great, I ran into this issue and your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, **jupytext** kept me from opening ipynb file becuase I edited ipynb file with another editor and not corresponding python file.

So I excuted `rm CORRESPONDING.py`, then I could open the ipynb file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message, and after a lot of trial and error,
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3706
gave the correct hint for my case:

The reason was a line ending thing. When editing the notebook in an external editor, I had left a superfluous comma in the last source block line of a code cell, i.e. `\n",` instead of correct `\n"`.